# CsvHelper: How to ignore the header row?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm using the [CsvHelper](https://nuget.org/packages/csvhelper) package to parse a TSV file.

I wish to process each record a time, without automatically deserializing into a class, as I need to process the fields individually.

However, even if I set `HasHeaderRecord = true`, I am getting the header returned as the first record in the loop.

The [docs](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper/CsvReader/) say: "Read() Advances the reader to the next record. This will not read headers. You need to call CsvHelper.CsvReader.Read then CsvHelper.CsvReader.ReadHeader for the headers to be read".

And [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/606) says: "Calling Read() will read in the current record. If you have a header record, you need to call ReadHeader afterwards".

But this still doesn't make sense to me, in the below code. Should I be calling `ReadHeader` for every row (within the loop)? That makes no sense, plus I tried and it throws an exception.

For now, I can just manually ignore the first record, but I am curious about the `ReadHeader` method, and my understanding of the above!

```cs
using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
csv.Configuration.Delimiter = "\t";
csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
while (csv.Read())
{
    if (csv.Context.Record.Length != numExpectedColumns)
    {
        errors++;
        continue;
    }

    int i = 0; // Calculate which index to be reading from based on various factors.
    string interestingField = csv[i];
}
```

Comment: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-by-hand

Comment: I would think that you call ReadHeader *once.*

Comment: As said in the linked github issue, `HasHeaderRecord` is used by automated stuff like `GetRecords` but not by manual read. You can test it and see that it's ignored https://dotnetfiddle.net/xJq8R4. The default value for `HasHeaderRecord` is `true` but if you specify false it will throw an error. For Why you have to read once first it's because in order to save on read Header comes from the context, the current row. before the first read there is no context and it will throw `No header **record** was found.` What it means is no record because read is what load the record.

Comment: Thanks @xdtTransform - if you post this as an answer, I will happy accept. This works, but I still not convinced it's the best API design.

Comment: I had no time to wrote an answer, I will if i find time and a real keyboard.